# What English word corresponds to the HTML keyword `div`?

Tags: html, tags

Most of the tags in hyper-text mark-up language (HTML) have an English word or phrase associated with that tag.

For example, the `kbd` tag is an abbreviation of the English word `keyboard`.

What English word or phrase is the `div` tag an abbreviation of?

---

Below is an example of code written in HTML which uses the `div` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 32):

The `DIV` element is first defined in the [HTML 3.0 standard](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/html3.txt):

> ### Divisions
>
> The DIV element is used with the CLASS attribute to represent different kinds of containers, e.g. chapter, section, abstract, or appendix.

And in the [3.2 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html32-20180315/#div):

> DIV elements can be used to structure HTML documents as a hierarchy of divisions.

It appears in an example in the [2.0 standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1866), but is never defined as a valid tag. The [4.0 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) instead describes it as "a generic mechanism for adding structure to documents".

Answer (score 11):

I have always assumed it stood for `division`.

[From w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_div.asp)

> The  tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document.

Comment: I would recommend against citing w3schools, if you can avoid it. They're wrong as often as they're right.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm not really in web dev, but it does seem like [they've cleaned up their act](https://www.w3fools.com/) since the early 2010s.

Comment: @detly They're no longer outright wrong most of the time, but it's still not high-quality content

Comment: @Bergi Useful to know. I won't argue that the canonical source is almost always a better reference anyway.

Comment: Plus, the same information is often available from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), which generally seems to be at least as reliable as w3schools is.

Comment: If nothing else, MDN cites its sources.